# Android Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: android, xml, styles, navigation-drawer, inflate-exception

**Error Message:**

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML
>   file line #16: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)

**xml file:**

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "edu.zhanglrose_hulman.bigbelly"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
    }
```

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

I've been searching everywhere, couldn't find the answer to my problem. Most of the answer that I found was keeping the design and appcompat same at the build.gradle. But it seems like I have that correctly set up. Please help me.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the complete stack trace, and to fix your formatting.

Comment: post your `styles.xml` file in the question..

Comment: @MikeM. Sorry about the format. I'm new to StackOverFlow.

Comment: @Ironman, I posted my styles.xml.

Comment: @user3914955 which device are you testing can you tell me the `API version` like `4.0` or something else..

Comment: can you provide the whole xml file with the error in line 16 as mentioned in the error message  please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error Occure because When Create New Project from `Android Studio`.The all base thing is setup. There's a drawable folder named **drawable-v21** which stores the icon xml files like this

**ic_menu_send.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M2.01,21L23,12 2.01,3 2,10l15,2 -15,2z" />
</vector>
```

so When you are testing from `below Api 21` you have put `ic_menu_send.png` file in your `drawable` folder to support below `Api 21`. Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

You can add values folder drawables.xml and add this:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item name="ic_menu_send" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_send</item>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like so:
I have a problem with dimen

```
<dimen name="nav_header_height">?attr/actionBarSize</dimen>
```

it was set in navigationview in

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
```

if i change it to any value it works good

```
android:layout_height="56dp"
```

Comment: or use directly `android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"`